# how to trim data in a cell in Excel 2007 VBA where there is a symbol

Tags: excel, vba

I want to trim the data inside the cell so that i have eveything before the hyphen

For example, if a cell contains:

```
'Net Operating Loss - All Pre-1990 Carryforwards'
```

i want to trim it in such a way that i only have:

```
'Net Operating Loss'
```

Any suggestions on how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim strSample As String

    strSample = "Net Operating Loss - All Pre-1990 Carryforwards"

    Debug.Print Split(strSample, "-")(0)
End Sub
```

BTW Do you need to do this in VBA. The above can be achieved using Excel Formulas as well.

Let's say you have "**Net Operating Loss - All Pre-1990 Carryforwards**" in Cell A1 then put this in Cell B1

**EXCEL 2003**

```
=IF(ISERROR(MID(A1,1,FIND("-",A1,1)-1)),"",MID(A1,1,FIND("-",A1,1)-1))
```

**EXCEL 2007 Onwards**

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,1,FIND("-",A1,1)-1),"")
```

Comment: +1 for seeing both sides through, and adding error check to Excel formula.

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

you use InStr to search for the hyphen and use the resulting position as length for the Right Command.

```
dim p as integer
p = InStr(YourStr, '-');
Trim(Right(YourStr, p - 1))
```

A little reference is here http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/index.php